# How to get Google Ads related metrics from Google Analytics 4 API?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

In GA4, I can view metrics related to Google Ads, such as Google Ads cost. Now I need to pull that metric via API (using Fivetran), but I cannot find that metric from the API. Even the GA4 explorer does not show such metric https://ga-dev-tools.web.app/ga4/dimensions-metrics-explorer/.

I would appreciate if someone can show me how to pull Google Ads related metrics as seen from GA4.

[image: Google Analytics Explorer]

Comment: you can find the valid dimensions and metrics for ga4 [here](https://ga-dev-tools.web.app/ga4/dimensions-metrics-explorer/)  you will probably not find all the metrics and dimensions are available.

Comment: I already mentioned that URL in the description

Comment: Exactly and those are the only dimension and metrics you can use.   We are limited by the dimensions and metrics google makes available to use via the api.